# Select de 3 tablas mysql

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

Tengo una query que ya trae información de 2 tablas, pero necesito añadir a la sentencia que me traiga información de la tabla llamada `locales` para que traiga el nombre del local que esta identificado con id desde la tabla `equipos`

Esta es la sentencia SQL que tengo en la que me trae los nombres de los equipos que estan con id en la tabla de `divisiones`, pero necesito que me traiga de la tabla equipos el `id del local` para sacar el nombre

```
SELECT

divisiones.start_date AS Fecha_Inicio,
  divisiones.tipo_liga AS Tipo_de_liga, 
  divisiones.zona_delegado AS Delegado, 
  divisiones.id_eq1 AS Equipo_1,
  eq1.name_eq AS Nombre_E1,
  divisiones.id_eq2 AS Equipo_2, 
  eq2.name_eq AS Nombre_E2,
  divisiones.id_eq3 AS Equipo_3, 
  eq3.name_eq AS Nombre_E3,
  divisiones.id_eq4 AS Equipo_4, 
  eq4.name_eq AS Nombre_E4,
  divisiones.id_eq5 AS Equipo_5, 
  eq5.name_eq AS Nombre_E5,
  divisiones.id_eq6 AS Equipo_6, 
  eq6.name_eq AS Nombre_E6,
  divisiones.id_eq7 AS Equipo_7, 
  eq7.name_eq AS Nombre_E7,
  divisiones.id_eq8 AS Equipo_8, 
  eq8.name_eq AS Nombre_E8,
  divisiones.id_eq9 AS Equipo_9,
  eq9.name_eq AS Nombre_E9,
  divisiones.id_eq10 AS Equipo_10,
  eq10.name_eq AS Nombre_E10

  FROM divisiones

  INNER JOIN equipos AS eq1
    ON divisiones.id_eq1 = eq1.id_eq
    INNER JOIN equipos AS eq2
    ON divisiones.id_eq2 = eq2.id_eq
    INNER JOIN equipos AS eq3
    ON divisiones.id_eq3 = eq3.id_eq
  INNER JOIN equipos AS eq4
    ON divisiones.id_eq4 = eq4.id_eq
    INNER JOIN equipos AS eq5
    ON divisiones.id_eq5 = eq5.id_eq
    INNER JOIN equipos AS eq6
    ON divisiones.id_eq6 = eq6.id_eq
  INNER JOIN equipos AS eq7
    ON divisiones.id_eq7 = eq7.id_eq
    INNER JOIN equipos AS eq8
    ON divisiones.id_eq8 = eq8.id_eq
    INNER JOIN equipos AS eq9
    ON divisiones.id_eq9 = eq9.id_eq
  INNER JOIN equipos AS eq10
    ON divisiones.id_eq10 = eq10.id_eq

  WHERE division_name = '$_POST[createPDF]'"
```

Esta es la tabla equipos, y necesito que traiga el campo `local` que es el id + el nombre que está en la misma tabla.

[image: Tabla equipos]

Gracias y saludos

Comment: estaria bien saber como tienes relacionas todas las tablas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> necesito que traiga el campo `local` que es el id + el nombre que está
>   en la misma tabla.

EDIT: con la información adicional

> los equipos contienen un campo que es id_local

La siguiente sentencia te traería el la división, el equipo y su local:

```
SELECT

  divisiones.start_date AS Fecha_Inicio,
  divisiones.tipo_liga AS Tipo_de_liga, 
  divisiones.zona_delegado AS Delegado, 
  divisiones.id_eq1 AS Equipo_1,
  eq1.name_eq AS Nombre_E1,
  lq1.nombre_local AS Local_E1

FROM divisiones
  INNER JOIN equipos AS eq1 
    ON divisiones.id_eq1 = eq1.id_eq
  INNER JOIN locales AS lq1 
   ON lq1.id_local = eq1.id_local
```

Esto ya no aplica:

<s>No me queda claro la forma del campo `id_local`, sólo asumí que es de la forma `<id_equipo>_<nombre_equipo>` (un underscore como separador). Pero con ese ejemplo puedes jugar hasta que cuadre, ya sea usando `CONCAT_WS` o simplemente `CONCAT` si no hay un sepadador.</s>

<s>**Nota1:** es poco eficiente que tengas que hacer el JOIN contra una función (que se evalúa en cada fila de la consulta) sería más sencillo que los equipos tuviesen un campo `id_local` o el local un campo `id_equipo`.</s>

---

**NOTA2:** la cláusula WHERE de la forma

```
WHERE division_name = '$_POST[createPDF]'"
```

Tiene dos problemas:

**Primero**: al interpolar una variable ingresada por el usuario, que no está sanitizada, te expones a una inyección SQL. Si alguien te envía por POST el valor

```
division1';DROP TABLE divisiones;--
```

tu sentencia se interpreta como:

```
SELECT ... FROM divisiones  
WHERE division_name = 'division1';
DROP TABLE divisiones;
--' // la comilla final queda comentada y se ignora
```

Eso significa que te eliminan la tabla. De hecho te pueden hacer cosas peores.

Necesitas usar una sentencia preparada. No te puedo decir exactamente cómo  hacerla porque no sé si estás usando `mysqli` o `PDO`, pero tendría la forma

```
$stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT *
  FROM divisiones
  WHERE division_name = ?");
```

Seguido de (mysqli)

```
 $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['createPDF']);
 $result = $stmt->execute();
```

O bien (PDO):

```
 $stmt->bindValue(1, $_POST['createPDF'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $result = $stmt->execute();
```

Lo importante es que uses una sentencia preparada y que, si estás usando el antiguo driver `mysql`, **cámbiate ya mismo** porque está descontinuado y es inseguro.

**Segundo**: $_POST[createPDF] es incorrecto. La variable a sanitizar es
$_POST['createPDF']. Si no está entrecomillada, PHP lo interpreta como una constante llamada `createPDF`, que no existe (y tira un error por debajo, sólo que no lo estás viendo porque debes tener deshabilitado `E_NOTICE`).

Comment: Hola buenas, el select que me has pasado no me devuelve nada... 

Lo que mencionas en la NOTA1: es asi, los equipos contienen un campo que es id_local, siento no haberlo mencionado, quizás esto facilita más todo